# SwiftUI - update target view during a transition

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, transition

I want to transition between two views in SwiftUI using a horizontal sliding transition. The problem is, that I also want to update the target view once the data is fetched from the network.

Down below is a minimal example of the transition. When the button on the first view is pressed, the transition and the (placeholder) background work is started. For better visibility, the transition is slowed down. In the second view, I have a `ProgressView` which should be replaced with the actual view (here a `Text` view) once the data is available.

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State private var push = false
    private let transition = AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing),
                                                      removal: .move(edge: .leading))
    private let transitionAnimation = Animation.easeOut(duration: 3)

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if !push {
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    HStack { Spacer() }
                    Spacer()

                    Button(action: {
                        push.toggle()
                        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                                self.viewModel.someText = "Test ### Test ### Test ### Test ### Test ### Test ###"
                            }
                        }
                    }){
                        Text("Go")
                    }

                    Spacer()
                }
                .background(Color.green)
                .transition(transition)
                .animation(transitionAnimation)
            } else {
                SecondView()
                    .transition(transition)
                    .animation(transitionAnimation)
                    .environmentObject(viewModel)
            }
        }
    }
}

final class ViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var someText: String = ""
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            HStack { Spacer() }
            Spacer()

            if(viewModel.someText.isEmpty) {
                ProgressView()
                    .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
            } else {
                Text(viewModel.someText)
            }

            Spacer()
        }.background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

The problem now is that the `Text` view is not included in the view transition. I would expect that it is moving along with the transition (= the red area), but instead, it just appears at the location where it would be after the transition. The following animation shows this effect.

[image]

Is it possible to achieve the animation of the `Text` view? To be clear: I know that in this case I could just always display the `Text` view because the string is empty at the beginning. As I stated earlier, this is a massively simplified version of my actual view hierarchy. I don't see a way of leaving out the `if-else` statement or use the `hidden` modifier.

Comment: [This](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-scrolling-pages-of-content-using-tabviewstyle) is not a solution to your problem, but if you are trying to create an onboarding screen, that may be what you need (easier to use built-in components). It is only a suggestion, but you may need the exact functionality you show instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately this approach is also not perfect. The question is related to [this issue](https://github.com/matteopuc/swiftui-navigation-stack/issues/55) on a SwiftUI navigation library on Github. I can get it working with the TabView, but animations can't be customized at all (at least I can't find a way to do so). It can't be slowed down for example like shown above.

Comment: I did not find a solution in SwiftUI yet, but I found this library: [https://github.com/knoggl/CleanUI](https://github.com/knoggl/CleanUI). Using the [CUNavigation](https://github.com/knoggl/CleanUI/blob/main/Sources/CleanUI/Main/Classes/CUNavigation.swift) class, I can achieve exactly the desired animations.

Answer (score 2):

Few things have to be done to make it work properly.

First, `Text` should exist in the views hierarchy even when the `someText` is empty. You can wrap it and the progress indicator into `ZStack` and control the text visibility with `.opacity` instead of the `if/else` statement.

Second, the animations can be applied conditionally depending on which value has changed. You should apply `transitionAnimation` only when the `push` variable is changed:

```
.animation(transitionAnimation, value: push)
```

There is a catch though: it won't work from the `if/else` branches on the same variable, because each of the `.animation` statements will exist only for one value of the `push` variable, and the changes in it won't be noticed. To fix that `if/else` should be wrapped into a `Group`, and animation should be applied to it.

Here is a full solution:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State private var push = false
    private let transition = AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .trailing),
                                                      removal: .move(edge: .leading))
    private let transitionAnimation = Animation.easeOut(duration: 3)

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Group {
                if !push {
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        HStack { Spacer() }
                        Spacer()

                        Button(action: {
                            push.toggle()
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                                self.viewModel.someText = "Test ### Test ### Test ### Test ### Test ### Test ###"
                            }
                        }){
                            Text("Go")
                        }

                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .background(Color.green)
                    .transition(transition)
                } else {
                    SecondView()
                        .transition(transition)
                        .environmentObject(viewModel)
                }
            }
            .animation(transitionAnimation, value: push)
        }
    }
}

final class ViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var someText: String = ""
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            HStack { Spacer() }
            Spacer()

            ZStack {
                if(viewModel.someText.isEmpty) {
                    ProgressView()
                        .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
                }
                Text(viewModel.someText)
                    .opacity(viewModel.someText.isEmpty ? 0.0 : 1.0)
            }

            Spacer()
        }.background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think the problem with this approach is that is works for simple cases like one text view, but it becomes much more complex for "real world" screens with a lot of elements where I would have to manually control the opacity of each element. Or am I missing something for that case?

Comment: @LN-12 yes, the approach requires you to modify the view hierarchy for the sake of animations, but it never caused many problems for me. You generally can control the opacity of a `Group` or other views containers instead of each individual subview.